# "No Such File in Directory" error when modifying resolv.conf in Nano

Tags: kali-linux, resolv.conf

When I edit `/etc/resolv.conf` (using `nano`) to add in the nameserver `8.8.8.8`, I get the following error when I save: No such file in directory.

However, when I go to the `/etc` directory, `resolv.conf` is there but in like this `resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resove/resolv.conf` in red.  I was able to edit the /etc/resolv.conf before but now I cant.

How may I add the nameserver to the `resolv.conf` file?

Comment: apparently your system is set up for systemd-resolved. Is systemd-resolved actually running? (systemd is notorious for messing with things in non-standard ways and inserting its claws into everything)

Comment: Thanks for your message, how do I check this and how do I get around this? Sorry not at all sure how this works, still a newb

Comment: If you're new to Linux-based systems, Jessica, please please don't start with Kali. Choose (almost) anything else, but specifically I'd recommend Mint, Ubuntu, or maybe Fedora if you want an rpm-based option

Comment: I totally understand but I am taking courses on Kali, so thats why I come here to get advice on my issue that I ran into. We all have to start somewhere no?

Comment: And before nano /etc/resolv.conf was working but now it isnt. So not sure how it just disappeared.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any nameservers yourself - they should be picked up through DHCP in the normal manner. (You are using DHCP...?)

Comment: Unfortunately there are many "hacking" courses for beginners that use Kali because "it's a distro for R34L H4CK3R5". Even if Kali's core functionality is different from basically all other Linux distros. If you're a Linux novice and taking a course that uses Kali, please don't get discouraged if you experience difficulties; try another distro (e.g Debian, Ubuntu, or RHEL-based ones such as Oracle Linux) before giving up. See also this Meta post: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 0):

You've been properly admonished about the use of Kali as a novice in the comments, so now an answer.

If you do an `ls -l`, you will see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group       4 May 23 13:56 that -> /somewhere/else/this
```

This means that `that` is a symbolic link to `this`. That is what the `l` in the first column means. This means that if you edit `that`, you are in fact editing `this`.

This works well enough, until `this` is removed. If only the file is removed, it will probably recreated. But if the directory is gone, than you will get the error message that you got.

Basically, `nano` says that it cannot create `/run/systemd/resove/resolv.conf` because `/run/systemd/resove` does not exist. Try `ls /run/systemd` to see if the directory is there.

If the `resove` is not a typo in the question (`resolve` with an `l`), than that is where your problem is.